# Linux dd command

Tags: linux, ssd, dd

I need to clone a faulty SSD. There are some I/O errors on the device. I would like to use a Linux `dd` command to make a copy.
I have some questions therefore.

1. What would be the best `bs` value in terms of future data recovery? Does this value affect a data recovery process in any way?
2. I would like to know which SSD blocks have I/O errors. Can `dd` create a log file and write it somewhere on the disk?

Any help will be appreciated. Regards

Comment: ddrescue is a better option.

Comment: Ditto. [Do not reinvent the wheel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572247/108618).

Answer (score 2):

While it can be done using dd, ddrescue is a utility written with with drives with bad sectors in mind.

Download for example [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage).

Depending on the goal you may prefer cloning drive to drive or drive to image. If the goal is file recovery I personally prefer the latter.

### **Using ddrescue**

```
ddrescue [options] infile outfile [logfile]
```

**To image from disk to disk:**

```
ddrescue -f -n /dev/[baddrive] /dev/[gooddrive] /root/recovery.log
```

**To image from disk to image file:**

```
ddrescue -f -n /dev/[baddrive] /root/[imagefilename].img /root/recovery.log
```

- -f   Force ddrescue to run even if the destination file already exists (this is required when writing to a disk). It will overwrite.
- -n   Short for’–no-scrape’. This option prevents ddrescue from running through the scraping phase, essentially preventing the utility from spending too much time attempting to recreate heavily damaged areas of a file.
- -c  Number of sectors to copy at a time. Defaults to 64 KiB.
- /dev/[baddrive]   Identifies the source drive that will be copied. Fill this in with the name of your bad drive.
- /dev/[gooddrive] or /root/[imagefilename].img   Identifies the destination drive or image file where the data will be cloned. Fill this in with either the name of the good drive or the image file name of your choice.
- /root/recovery.log   This creates a logfile, which is essential if you’re performing multiple passes. You can name the logfile anything. Without a logfile, you can’t make additional passes on areas of your disk with bad sectors.

Everything on ddrescue: https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue

Another guide on using ddrescue to clone a drive: https://www.data-medics.com/forum/threads/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-with-bad-sectors-using-ddrescue.133/

### Block Size and data recovery

There's no generic answer to the question "what's the optimal block size?". In general I'd say you pick the largest block size you can get away with as it gives you more speed. On a drive that is in pretty good condition, this is easier than when you're dealing with a drive that's in a poor shape.

As a rule of thumb we could use, the poorer the shape of the drive, the smaller the block size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Joep . I was definitely convinced to use ddrescue (I wasn't aware of this program before). Another question bothers me in this matter. Is it a very bad idea to use as a rescue drive (the one the data will be cloned to), a HDD that was in use earlier for data storage?  I'm asking in terms of future data recovery. Should HDD be totally wiped off with a some dedicated data erase program?

Comment: A lab will indeed used a wiped drive as destination for the clone if they clone *disk-to-disk*. When cloning *disk-to-file* it's not an issue.

Comment: Hello @Joep . I have one more question. I made a copy of this faulty drive with a command: `ddrescue -d -n /dev/sda backup.img recovery.log` . It took 1.5 h to clone a 500GB disk with one pass. I want to run another pass using a recovery.log previously created. If I write `ddrescue -d -r3 -R -A /dev/sda backup.img recovery.log` ddrescue will reuse the info from recovery.log or it will overwrite the log file and start from the beginning again?

Comment: That sounds good. Why the need to re-run? ddrescue should use the logfile but I'm rusty on ddrescue, haven't used it myself for ages as I now use pro tools for this type of tasks.

Comment: I want to re-run ddrescue because there are '/' & '-' marks in the log file that, as I understand, indicate "failed block non-scraped" & "failed block bad-sector(s)"

Comment: Usually there's not much use in retrying bad sectors. The forte of tools like ddrescue is not bad sector recovery but the ability to not hang but instead work around them as much as possible, and then during consecutive passes target skipped sectors that were not bad.